# How to monitor testing progress with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, unit-testing, testing, azure-devops

I would like to measure the testing progress (how many tests are done, how many passed/failed, how many tests run by a specific tester) in MS Azure DevOps.

I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-test-results-trend?view=azure-devops) article and it seems Test Results Trend widget is what I need (plus the widget is enabled on my installation).

Now, I have the test plan with the test suites and test cases. But the widget works with the pipelines. My knowledge is very limited here... but I would expect one should be able to build a pipeline from the test suite.

Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Do you mean to Unit Tests or to manual test - QA?

Comment: Manual tests (have a test suite created with a number of test cases)

Comment: Check my answer :)

Comment: @Vasek did you tried with below answer of Shayki Abramczyk. It seems like the right widget for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Test Results Trend widget is for Unit Tests (that executed during a build pipeline), what do you need is Chart for Test Plan:

[image]

There you can configure the widget to display Test Cases / Test Runs (according to Tets Plan/Suite).

In the "Test Plans" page you can also configure charts that display that information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Shayki Abramczyk.

I've used the widget you suggest before. The problem there is that you can only see the actual status. It's not possible to monitor the testing progress, i. e. the number of planned test vs the actual number of performed (passed/failed) tests.



To the best of my knowledge,  it's not possible to monitor the progress neither with Test Results Trend widget nor directly in the test plan page/chart.